# Is there a specific word for the love of watching gross videos?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word to describe love for watching gross, but oddly satisfying, videos (like on TikTok or instagram) where they extract blackheads or pop pimples?

Comment: [Prurient](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prurient) might be close, though it generally has a sexual aspect.

Comment: There are terms for people who like to watch videos of people dying (e.g. ghoul, ghoulishness) but perhaps not for this more innocent form of grossness.

Comment: @StuartF I'm not sure it is entirely innocent. Bank robbers might begin with shoplifting.

Comment: It's hard to see much harm in pimple popping videos, but maybe they are a gateway to worse things.

Comment: Depravity, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a contemporary  form of ***[voyeurism](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/voyeurism)*** in the sense of:

> ​pleasure gained from watching the problems and private lives of others.

(OLD)